# Elastic search in two different directory

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have Admin panel in whole new directory and front in whole new directory.

Like,

Admin is different and Front is different.(Two different custom php project one is for admin and one is for front), so If I create elastic search document in admin to sync all data, will it be available in front direcotry?

Answer (score 1):

its depend on where you install and host your elastic search, 
ex : 
Server A
Server B
Server C

If you configure your elastic in Server B, then you just need to Serve it to Server A and Server C,
You can access it from whatever application, as long as you whitelist an IP for request in another server

Good luck